# the router does not transmit id - Angular

Tags: angular

The router does not transmit id. Id in the link `http://localhost:4200/user/products/$%7Bid%7D` is not forwarded.

The value `${userid}` after refreshing the page is not passed:

**src/app/core/navbar/navbar.component.html:**

```jshtml
<li class="nav-item dropdown" >
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" *ngIf="!!authService.isLoggedIn_()" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              My profil
   </a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="background-color:#71b9d4;  opacity: 0.9; filter: Alpha(opacity=90); color:white">

         <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="user/products/${userid}">List products</a>                 
   </div>
</li>
```

After selecting `routerLink ="user/products/${userid}"` this page should be displayed:

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Add product
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form  [formGroup]="produktForm" (ngSubmit)="saveProduct(produktForm.value)">
        <label for="product_name">Name product </label>
        <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control" formControlName="product_name" [(ngModel)]="product_name"/>          
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add product...</button>           
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Your product list
  </div>
  <table class="table table-hover">       
    <tr>
      <td>Product name</td>         
      <td colspan="2">Action</td>
    </tr>        
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products_; let productIndex = index">
      <td><input required value="{{product.product_name}}" name="product.product_name"  class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="product.product_name" /></td>           
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="updateProduct(product)" >Edition</button></td>
      <td><button  type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteProduct(productIndex, product._id)" >Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

when refresh the page shows up:
`{"success":true,"data":[]}`

**src/app/products.service.ts:**

```typescript
getProducts(userid) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', `${this.jwtToken}`);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:4200/user/products/${userid}`, options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**code server.js contains:**

```js
app.get('/user/products/:id', product.selectproducts);
```

**method `product.selectproducts` :**

```typescript
exports.selectproducts = function (req, res, next) {
    products.find({
    userid: req.params.id
  }).exec(function (err, product) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error processing request ' + err
      });
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      data: product
    });
    console.log(product);
  });
}
```

How to get the value `userid: req.params.id`, after page refreshing?

Comment: `[routerLink]="'user/products/'+userid"`

Comment: `userid` - error : [Angular] Identifier 'userid' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameter like this:

```
[routerLink]="[ 'user/products', { id: userid } ]"
```

Also you can to use syntax like

```
[routerLink]="'user/products/' + userid"
```

or

```
routerLink="user/products/{{ userid }}"
```

Comment: `[routerLink]="[ 'user/products', { id: userid } ]"` -> `http://localhost:4200/user/products;id=undefined` in method: `ngOnInit() {
    this.userObj = this.authService.currentUser;
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
      if (params.id) {
        this.productid = params['id'];
        console.log('(params.id)' + params.id);  // (params.id)undefined
      }
    });
}`

Comment: I do not understand why after refreshing the page the `constructor` or the `ngOnInit` method does not call?

Comment: the error is with passing `console.log(req.params.id)` displays correctly the first time, but after refreshing the page displays`${userid}`